# Created image share folder on live server and display on local server

Tags: php, wamp

I have live server where my website is located which have root directory `www->mysite->images` which shows images on live. I have second server where same website is uplaoded except images folder I want to show images from live server. But I cannot sort it out. How I can do it I made my images folder as share folder on live server but on second server images shown broken. I am doing on wamp server Apache 2.4 the share folder path is look like this `\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\images` when I write this path on second server run the images folder open and show images but in root directory share folder shortcut is not showing images. N page broken images shown.

I made my images folder as share folder on live server but on second server images shown broken.

Comment: did you check the console in chrome?

Comment: i did it there am getting src="images/logo.jpg" but shows broken image. actually i dnt want to copy the image folder from live server to local server want to get image from live server

Comment: images are broken that means url may be wrong , if image is not found it will display an 404 error in console , is there any error in your console?

Comment: whats name of your live server website ?

Comment: getting 404 error. bcz cannot access it via sharefolder

Comment: its on intranet

Comment: its not accessible from out ?

Comment: We have no idea whether you set up the share correctly, whether a network path exists between the two, what testing you've done, whether your other app is using the correct folder name etc etc. All you've done is described the symptoms of the problem. You've given us no details by which we could try to diagnose the problem. There could be a number of different reasons for this